# Onclick event: divs appear one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, onclick

Is it possible to make based on this actual one div at a time, that is to say both of the two events onclick can't open , but if one is open and the other one is clicked the first automatically close. By the way the context which this code is used doesn't allow the use of Jquery. Thanks for your help

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .link{text-decoration:none; color:white;}

  .link:visited{color:white}

.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */
  
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}

div {font-family:'Varela Round';
}
  
  .opener {
  background-color: #07183d;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px white solid;
}

.benefits {
  background-color: #07183d;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width:300px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#upbutton {
  border: 1px dotted white;
}
</style>
<script>function show(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='none') { 
            document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='block'; 
        } 
        return false;
    } 
    function hide(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='block') { 
            document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='none'; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
</script>
<div class="row">
<div class="opener col"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show('1');" class="link">SOCIETES: 400</a>

<div class="benefits" id="b1" style="display:none;">Part SBF 120 : 120<br />
Part Filiales +100M€: 280
<div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide('1');" >fermer</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="opener col"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show('2');" class="link" >CONTACTS: 25 400</a>

<div class="benefits col" id="b2" style="display:none;">Part CAC 40 : 15 700<br />
Part Filiales +100M€: 9 700<br />
% contacts IT: 21%
<div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide('2');">fermer</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="opener col">EMAILS NOMINATIFS: 400</div>

<div class="opener col">OPT OUT: 3%</div>

  <div class="opener col">LIGNES DIRECTES: 35%</div></div>
```

Comment: change id to class

Comment: the id="upbutton"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the other elements and close them first in your "show" function

```
function show(id) { 

    var benefits = document.getElementsByClassName("benefits");
    for(var i = 0; i<benefits.length; i++){
        benefits[i].style.display="none";
    }

    if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='none') { 
        document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='block'; 
    } 

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function show(id) { 
var v = parseInt(id);
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("benefits");
//var num = list.length;

if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='none')       { 
    document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='block'; 
} 

for (i = v+1; i <= list.length ; i++) { 
if(document.getElementById('b'+i).style.display=='block')       { 
    document.getElementById('b'+i).style.display='none';
}
}
for (i = v-1; i >=0 ; i--) { 
if(document.getElementById('b'+i).style.display=='block')       { 
    document.getElementById('b'+i).style.display='none';
}
}


return false;
}
```